# TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Tags: python, django

I have a DetailView that displays a user's profile page. The profile takes a slug name that is part of the URL. For example, `/profile/john/` where `john` is the username, and we are on john's profile. As shown here:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'oauth/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_profile' 

    def post(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Now whenever I submit a form, I get an error that says: `TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'` Knowing this, I added a new argument in the post method which is slug. However, when I submit the form, I get a blank page with no details about the user. We get redirected to the same page, but this time with no values about the user profile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `slug` as method argument also:

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    return render(request, self.template_name)
```

You need to pass context to the template as well:

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

But actually since your post doesn't add specific logic to the view you can just call `super`:

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    return super().post(request, slug)
```

Or simply remove `post` method completely cause it's redundant.

Comment: I did, I've written about what happened when I did that in the question, for some reason it's still not working. It displays the same page, but with no user profile details

Comment: @user2896120 you need to pass context to the template.

Comment: What is context in context=context?

Comment: @user2896120 it's result if `get_context_data` function. See updates.

Comment: I see, so what happens is we want to get the context data of the current profile object and then we pass that context data to the page render

Comment: @user2896120 correct. But all this things made by class based view automatically, so in this example overriding `post()` method is redundant.

Comment: I do have logic, but I removed it to make things simpler. Even if I do have logic, is it still redundant?

Comment: @user2896120 Ah, No if you implement some custom logic then it's not redundant.